# StructureMapConfigurationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I'm building and ASP.NET MVC 4.5. I've added StructureMap to my project. I've created in my website and Ioc class:

```
public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Ebancomat"].ConnectionString;

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<Ebancomat.DataAdapters.IncomeExpenses.IIncomeExpensesDataAdapter>().Use<Ebancomat.DataAdapters.IncomeExpenses.IncomeExpensesDataAdapter>().Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(connectionString);
            x.For<Ebancomat.Repositories.IncomeExpenses.IIncomeExpensesRepository>().Use<Ebancomat.Repositories.IncomeExpenses.IncomeExpensesRepository>();
        });

        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
```

and a StructureMapControllerFactory  class:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IContainer container;

    public StructureMapControllerFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        var instance = container.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;

        if (instance == null)
        {
            return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

I've added this isn my Global.asax.cs:

```
var container = Ioc.Initialize();
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory(container));
```

When I've first run the application, a window had opened and it wanted Container.cs . I didn't find that class, I pressed Cancel and since then I get this error and I don't understand why. (I tried the same code at work and there it was working perfectly)

```
An exception of type 'StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException' occurred in StructureMap.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IUserStore<ApplicationUser>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's asking for Container.cs because that is the class within StructureMap that's throwing the exception; since you're (I assume) referencing the StructureMap.DLL binary, you won't have the source. I wouldn't worry about that.

It looks like you're calling `ObjectFactory.GetInstance` on a type that you haven't registered.

Your `ObjectFactory.Initialize` registers concrete types for `IIncomeExpensesDataAdapter` and `IIncomeExpensesRepository`, but I can't see anything for `IUserStore<ApplicationUser>` or `IUserStore<T>`

Can you search your code for `ObjectFactory.GetInstance` and see if there's anywhere you're using this without registering the object graph in StructureMap ?

Comment: I searched. No there isn't .

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `IUserStore<ApplicationUser>` is being resolved via constructor injection and SM cant resolve it because it is not registered within container. So all you need is to register `IUserStore<ApplicationUser>` in the container.

I would also get rid of `ObjectFactory` in favour of `new Container`

```
public static IContainer Initialize()
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Ebancomat"].ConnectionString;

    return new Container(
        c =>
            {
                c.For<Ebancomat.DataAdapters.IncomeExpenses.IIncomeExpensesDataAdapter>()
                    .Use<Ebancomat.DataAdapters.IncomeExpenses.IncomeExpensesDataAdapter>()
                    .Ctor<string>("connectionString")
                    .Is(connectionString);
                c.For<Ebancomat.Repositories.IncomeExpenses.IIncomeExpensesRepository>()
                    .Use<Ebancomat.Repositories.IncomeExpenses.IncomeExpensesRepository>();
                c.For<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Use<DatabaseUserStore>();
        });
}
```

Comment: I tried your way, but I have another problem; I don't know where to find "DatabaseUserStore" to add the using .

Comment: @MarianEne this type is fake. I used is for this code snippet purposes. You should use the one you are using.